# How to passing array from View to Controller

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I have problem I got some data from database into array and pass it to View. In View I print the array. And I will to do button that when I clicked in then I delete one item from array and again print it.

I don't have idea, how i can pass this array from view again to the controller to redirect again.

Do you have any clues or maybe idea for do this in other way?

Thanks

Comment: First passing data from view to controller.. is not std way....  ot u can pass with GET method using js 'window. location.href=test.xom?$encoded_array' or ajax post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a new request, either via Ajax or the traditional way because processing of the change of content will be executed in another PHP execution

Comment: I do in GET request:                                            $words = Auth::user()->words();
return View::make('home')->with('word', $words);                              And then in home View i print word and how I can do that when i click button I get the same array but without one item? In controller I have to do again $words = Auth::user()->words(); and again pass to view (before delete one item)?

Comment: $words = $_GET['words'];